# relative pronoun's "role" in a relative clause

Tags: gramática

> El primer artículo del libro gira en torno al doble desafío que abre la contemporaneidad en el espacio hispanoamericano: las revoluciones e independencias.

1. Is *desafío* the antecedent of *que abre la contemporaneidad en el espacio hispanoamericano*?
2. If the correct translation is "that the Modern era opens up" or "that opens up the Modern era", why is it correct?
3. And can anyone cite a Spanish resource that helps a person answer a question such as the above question?

The subject sentence comes from a user who did not cite his/her source.

Answer (score 1):

I understand "contemporaneidad" to mean "[Edad Contemporánea](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_de_la_era_contempor%C3%A1nea)", which is the era between the French Revolution and now. This is not a standard use of the word "[contemporaneidad](https://dle.rae.es/contemporaneidad)", but is [sometimes seen](https://concepto.de/edad-contemporanea/).

I understand "abre la contemporaneidad" as "marks the beginning of the Contemporary Era", based on the 16th definition of [abrir](https://dle.rae.es/abrir):

> 16. tr. Comenzar ciertas cosas o darles principio, inaugurar.

Therefore, I understand the sentence as

- The first chapter of the book is about the double challenge that marks the beginning of the Contemporary Era in Latin America: the revolutions and the independence declarations.

So *desafío* is indeed the antecedent of *que abre la contemporaneidad en el espacio hispanoamericano*.

Regarding your third question, the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es) is a good dictionary to find obscure (and not obscure) meanings of words. I would not know which other source to recommend in this case, though I agree that the sentence is complicated because it uses some not very standard meanings of words.

Comment: You have provided something worth thinking about, and I thank you for doing so.

Comment: <<The first chapter of the book is about the double challenge that marks the beginning of the Contemporary Era in Latin America: the revolutions and the independence declarations.>>  Then the subject of the relative clause is the word "that"?

Comment: Yes, from what I learned about syntax, the subject of the clause "que abre la contemporaneidad en el espacio hispanoamericano" is the relative pronoun "que". I assume it should be the same in the English version.

Comment: Is "que abre la contemporaneidad en el espacio hispanoamericano" a restrictive or non-restrictive clause?

Comment: @user326251 I would say restrictive, as it narrows down which challenge we are talking about. Removing that clause would make the sentence too ambiguous.

Comment: Especificativa?  (I guess the lack of commas is a dead giveaway for restrictive clauses.)